# Why isn't my recursion working?

Tags: java

Why isn't my code working? I'm trying to implement a recursive method that will return the number of digits an integer has. Here is my code:

```
public int numOfDigits(int num) {
    if (num < 10)
        return 1;
    return numOfDigits(num / 10);
}
```

Comment: `return 1 + numOfDigits(num / 10);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When dividing `num` by `10`, you're getting rid of one digit (the last one), but you forget to add it to the result.

You code you need should be more like:

```
public int numOfDigits(int num) {
    if (num < 10)
        return 1;
    return 1 + numOfDigits(num / 10);
}
```

... which can be reduced to a one liner with the ternary operator:

```
public int numOfDigits(int num) {
    return (num < 10) ? 1 : 1 + numOfDigits(num / 10);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The final call of `numOfDigits` which blocks the recursion returns 1. This value simply bubbles up to the initial caller.

The fix is to write `return 1 + numOfDigits(num / 10/*integral division removes a digit*/);`

Assuming you're not doing this by recursion for fun, once you have the algorithm working, replace it with a simple loop: using recursion here is wasteful in terms of stack frame creation etc.

As for alternatives, note that taking the base 10 logarithm can cause you problems with precision. The fastest way I know is

```
final static int [] sizeTable = { 9, 99, 999, 9999, 99999, 999999, 9999999,
                                  99999999, 999999999, Integer.MAX_VALUE };

// Requires positive x
static int digits(int x) {
    for (int i=0; ; i++)
        if (x <= sizeTable[i])
            return i+1;
}
```

Code stolen from the library for Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int numOfDigits(int num) {
    if (num < 10)
        return 1;
    return numOfDigits(num / 10);
}
```

This works fine, it's just you don't understand it. For example you call it

```
numOfDigits(1000)
```

original `num = 1000`
when you get to

```
return numOfDigits(num / 10);
```

in reality you are calling `return numOfDigits(100);`
which will run this method again but this time `num = 100`

so when you get to `return numOfDigits(num / 10);`

in reality you are calling `return numOfDigits(10);`
which will run this method again but this time `num = 10`
10 is not less than 10, so you will get to `return numOfDigits(num / 10);` one more time and this time you are calling `return numOfDigits(1);`

With `num = 1` 
the `if statement` will be `true` for first time

```
if (num < 10)
        return 1;
```

Meaning this method no matter what will always `return 1`.

The only difference is how many loops it will take to do so.